# Which version of BASIC uses RANDOM for seeding the random number generator (RNG)?

Tags: basic

Which version of BASIC uses `RANDOM` as the pseudo-random seed command?

I believe that the following is correct, given the linked-to articles:

- [Atari BASIC](https://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue90/The_Beginners_Page.php) uses `RANDOMIZE`
- [C64 BASIC](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/RND) uses  `RND(-<n>)`
- ZX BASIC has `RAND` as the keyboard token, but the actual code was *totally* inconsistant:

  - ZX80 uses `RANDOMISE`
  - ZX81 uses `RAND`
  - ZX Spectrum (48k/128k) uses `RANDOMIZE`
- [BBC BASIC](https://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/wiki/doku.php?id=notes_20on_20the_20use_20of_20rnd) uses `RND(-<n>)`
- [AppleSoft BASIC](https://www.landsnail.com/a2ref.htm) uses `RND(-<n>)`<sup>1</sup>
- [MS BASIC-80](https://ia800708.us.archive.org/8/items/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual_text.pdf) uses `RANDOMIZE`
- [TI-BASIC](http://shawweb.myzen.co.uk/stephen/book2.htm) uses `RANDOMIZE`
- QBASIC uses `RANDOMIZE`
- [Locomotive BASIC](https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/Locomotive_BASIC#RANDOMIZE_.5Bseed.5D) uses `RANDOMISE` / `RANDOMISE TIME`

I can't find a variant that uses `RANDOM`.

---

I only ask as the listing 2 in [my answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/25641/202) to [Early 1982 PCW article about pseudo random dungeon mapping](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11041/202) has the following line:

```
70 RANDOM
```

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> With `PEEK(78)` and `PEEK(79)` being [commonly used](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19753/202) to augment/supplement the randomness

Comment: For completion, QBASIC uses `RANDOMIZE`

Comment: The `PEEK(78)` and `PEEK(79)` in the linked post aren't part of the RNG, they're being used as an *input* to `RND(-<n>)`, using system memory to get some entropy.

Comment: @IMSoP - ah yes, you are quite correct.... I'll update the post

Comment: Another one for your list: Locomotive BASIC uses `RANDOMISE` / `RANDOMISE TIME` : https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/Locomotive_BASIC#RANDOMIZE_.5Bseed.5D

Comment: note that `RAND` is in ZX81 BASIC, while the ZX Spectrum has `RANDOMIZE` (but ZX80  had `RANDOMISE` (!))

Comment: @RadovanGarabík - Sorry just checked all three on an online emulator, you are right. Updated question. Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RANDOM is the keyword [TRS-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80) [Level II BASIC](http://www.trs-80.org/level-2-basic/) uses to seed the random number generator. For a description [see here](https://www.trs-80.com/wordpress/info-level-2-basic-language/#Random).

---

*On a side note, the BASIC used is mentioned in the referred article right beside the listing:*
[image]